# Multithreaded double buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I have a `Buffer` class that implements the [double buffer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) designed with multithreading in mind:

```
class Buffer {
public:
   void write(size_t idx, float value) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
      (*next)[idx] = value; // write to next buffer
   }

   float read(size_t idx) const {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
      return (*current)[idx]; // read from current buffer
   }

   void swap() noexcept {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
      std::swap(current, next); // swap pointers
   }

   Buffer() : buf0(32), buf1(32), current(&buf0), next(&buf1) { }
private:
   std::vector<float> buf0, buf1; // two buffers
   std::vector<float> *current, *next;
   mutable std::mutex mut;
};
```

This class contains two buffers. The buffers are always accessed through pointers:

- A buffer where reading from, specified by `current` pointer.
- A buffer where writing to, specified by `next` pointer.

There will be two threads: an updating thread will write to the next buffer calling the `write` method, a reading thread will read from the current buffer calling the `read` method. When the updating thread is done it calls `swap` to swap the pointers to the buffers.

**The swapping of the buffers must be done atomically** so I have to lock the mutex in every method (creating the `lk` object).

The problem is that locking the mutex in every method prevents the two threads from accessing their corresponding buffer at the same time. But the two buffers are independent: there is no problem if one thread modifies one buffer while the other thread reads the other buffer.

I want to allow the updating thread to modify its buffer at the same time the reading thread reads its corresponding buffer. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe two mutexes: one only for reading and another for writing. `swap()` must lock these both mutexes.

Comment: Who is calling `swap()` in your code? The reader or the writer? While you have locks in place that make swaps atomics and reads and writes to *individual elements* of the two buffers atomic, there is nothing that really makes access to a buffer *as a whole* atomic.

Comment: @G.Sliepen The writer calls swap() when it is done.

Comment: That means that if a reader wants, for example, to get the difference of two values, by writing `float diff = buffer.read(1) - buffer.read(0)`, then while the two reads are atomic, the writer can call `buffer.swap()` between the two reads. The end result is then probably not what you would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to solve your problem is by using one mutex per buffer and protect your swap with both.
If the swap is safely used in a synchronous way between the two threads, you can safely remove the lock inside (however it seems to not be the case in your code).

Here is an example:

```
class Buffer {
public:
   void write(size_t idx, float value) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutWrite);
      (*next)[idx] = value; // write to next buffer
   }

   float read(size_t idx) const {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutRead);
      return (*current)[idx]; // read from current buffer
   }

   void swap() noexcept {
      // Lock both mutexes safely using a deadlock avoidance algorithm
      std::lock(mutWrite, mutRead);
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lkWrite(mutWrite, std::adopt_lock);
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lkRead(mutRead, std::adopt_lock);

      // In C++17, you can replace the 3 lines above with just the following:
      // std::scoped_lock lk( mutWrite, mutRead );

      std::swap(current, next); // swap pointers
   }

   Buffer() : buf0(32), buf1(32), current(&buf0), next(&buf1) { }
private:
   std::vector<float> buf0, buf1; // two buffers
   std::vector<float> *current, *next;
   mutable std::mutex mutRead;
   std::mutex mutWrite;
};
```