# Why does locking a mutex in one thread slow down another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I'm experiencing some issues in the process of introducing `mutex` into my application, to enable multi-thread compatibilities.

I've got one thread for building user data, and another thread for rendering data. lets call these two threads as `thread-1` and `thread-2`.

1. I created the data in `thread-1`
2. Then invoked lock() and pushed the data into array,
3. Then invoked unlock() on `thread-1`
4. Then tried to read the data written in `thread-1` , from`thread-2`using the following steps:
5. Invoked lock() on `thread-2`
6. loop the array display the user data
7. Invoked unlock() in `thread-2`

Since `thread-2` is faster than `thread-1` it causes a lag in the rendering process. Removing the `lock()` and `unlock()` from `thread-2` solves that issue.

Can anyone please explain what's the reason for this?

Comment: Are you using std::mutex? If so lock with std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> or std::unique_lock<std::mutex>. Like this : `std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx};`. Locks need to be as short as possible, and you're running into 'there is no free lunch' issue. Thread syncrhonization takes time and you need to take this into account in your design.

Comment: I am using std::mutex PlayerData; to be exact, then I fill a huge array this takes time unfortunately as there is a lot of data that needs to be filled

Comment: Probably what thread2 needs to do, while it has the mutex, is copy the data (e.g. to an array it controls) as quickly as possible, and scrub the shared data.   Then do actions to display when it is not holding the mutex.   This allows thread1 to repopulate the data while thread2 is drawing the data it has.    Doing the drawing while holding mutex effectively means that thread1 is forced to wait most of the time while thread2 is working.

Comment: If you remove the lock and unlock from thread 2, then you will have no thread synchronization, and you may be possibly rendering corrupt data in thread 2, because there is no guarantee that the data is in a consistent state when you read it.

Comment: Use double buffering, have two copies of data. One in which you write, if it is full swap (pointers to) the buffers within the lock. Then let thread 2 read from the read copy. The advantage is that thread 2 can keep reading from that while thread 1 is still writing a new version.

Comment: I did a quick search and there is an example here : [multithreaded-double-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351527/multithreaded-double-buffer)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, and yes that is unfortunately what I suspected would happen though Peter I think has told me the solution here.

Inside of thread2 I create a new array of my class like this


`std::vector<GameActors> PlayerDataArray_New;


mutex.lock();

PlayerDataArray_New = PlayerDataArray (this is the data being set in thread1)

mutex.unlock();`


//render the data inside of the PlayerDataArray_New instead of .lock(); for loop the data being set in thread1 .unlock()

Correct?

Comment: Not locking on both threads may result in one thread not seeing a consistent state of the data. If both threads have to hold the lock for doing most of the work you'll end up with only the drawbacks of multithreading, but not it's benefits. You may be able to fix this issue by working with 2 copies of the data that and locking the mutex only for exchanging the copies of the threads,e.g. `std::vector<Data>data; ...expensive computations ... { std::lock_guard lock(mutex); renderThreadData.swap(data);  /* <-- inexpensive operation */ }` You may even be able to go lockfree using `std::atomic`...

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing, but you could look at atomic operations (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), potentially holding the data your are editing in something like a shared_ptr. That way you can update the shared_ptr when you are editing on the first thread and retrieving the pointer on the second thread does not require a lock and will have well defined behaviour. You would need to use something like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_load and exchange to set/get pointer.

Comment: Are you only rendering a single frame? Or are you rendering several frames per second? If it is the latter, then you may want to consider having two buffers and have each thread working on a single buffer at a time: One buffer will be used by Thread 1 for generating the data for the next frame, and the other buffer will contain the data required for Thread 2 to render the current frame. Once both threads have finished their work, you can swap the buffers, so that Thread 2 starts rendering the data previously generated by Thread 1 and Thread 1 starts working on the next frame.

Comment: A [mre] would help illustrate your question

Comment: Note that you should also take [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) into account. You should design your program in such a way that the memory access pattern minimizes this. Since a cache line is generally 64 bytes, you should not have two threads frequently accessing memory locations that are less than 64 bytes apart, unless these memory accesses are read-only from all threads. (False sharing is not a problem for read-only access).

Comment: Thank you for all your responses. The idea that Peter has suggested seems to have fixed my problem that I lock, copy data, unlock, then use the copied data rather than locking then rendering then unlocking. I still think there are some core logic flaws to my code from the responses and will be taking a look into those!

Comment: Instead of general locking, something like a data queue or double buffer seems to fit much better. In this case you need to lock only the access of queue management and not the usage of the data itself and you can wight the threads by locking only if your queues or buffers are full. One data store and general locking during work on the data is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the spin lock, and spin lock could used in those situation where the threads have more freqence switch and more compute task in short time, spin lock make the thread is looping itself and could not in sleeping, here are example code below, you could run on you machine and check the result:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_spinlock_t spinlock;

pthread_t tid_1;
pthread_t tid_2;

using namespace std;

#define LOOP_NUM 100000

#define MUTEX_LOCK

#ifdef MUTEX_LOCK

void* thread_func(void *param) {

    int *p = (int *)param;
    int i = 0;
    while( i++ < LOOP_NUM) {

      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

      std::cout << ++(*p) << std::endl;

      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

#else

void* thread_func(void *param) {

    int *p = (int *)param;
    int i = 0;
    while( i++ < LOOP_NUM) {

      pthread_spin_lock(&spinlock);

      std::cout << ++(*p)  << std::endl;

      pthread_spin_unlock(&spinlock);
    }
}

#endif


int main() {

    int i = 0;

    struct timeval tv_start;
    struct timeval tv_end;

    gettimeofday(&tv_start, NULL);

#ifdef MUTEX_LOCK
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
#else    
    pthread_spin_init(&spinlock, 0);
#endif    

    pthread_create(&tid_1, NULL, thread_func, &i);

    pthread_create(&tid_2, NULL, thread_func, &i);

    pthread_join(tid_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid_2, NULL);

    gettimeofday(&tv_end, NULL);

    std::cout<< "spend time:" << (tv_end.tv_sec-tv_start.tv_sec) * 1000 \
    + (tv_end.tv_usec - tv_start.tv_usec)/1000  << " ms" << std::endl;

#ifdef MUTEX_LOCK
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
#else
    pthread_spin_destroy(&spinlock);
#endif        


}
```

Here are the result, when I run 10 times by the mutex lock (millisecond):
6156
5989
5851
5489
8249
6215
5921
6361
6346
6434

And here are the result using spin lock(millisecond):
5434
4489
4713
5519
4868
4832
5287
5670
5270
5200

You will find that using spin lock is faster than mutex lock, nearly 1 second on my machine.

Comment: The lock itself might be faster, but this has really nothing to do with the problem that the use case of the lock is to protect the access of data and this access is blocked to long. For my eyes your answer did not help for nothing...

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, you should measure how much time each thread is spending with the mutex locked, and minimize that amount of time as much as possible.  That will reduce the amount of time the other thread might have to spend waiting to acquire the lock.

One straightforward way to minimize the amount of time either thread spends holding the lock is to use double-buffering, i.e. give each thread its own private data-structure, plus a third data-structure that is shared between the two threads and serialized by the mutex.

Then, instead of each thread doing:

```
1. lock mutex
2. read or write to data-structure (which could take some time)
3. unlock mutex
```

... your writer would do this:

```
1. Write new data to writer's private data-structure (which could take some time)
2. lock mutex
3. swap writer's private data structure with shared data structure (fast!)
4. unlock mutex 
5. clear writer's private data structure
```

... and your reader would do this:

```
1. clear reader's private data structure
2. lock mutex
3. swap reader's private data structure with shared data structure (fast)
4. unlock mutex
5. Use data in reader's private data structure (which could take some time)
```

Most data structures can do a swap-operation in O(1) time (i.e. by swapping just two internal pointers) so this allows lock-contention to be extremely minimal in all cases.  (If your performance requirements are so fine-grained that even doing context-switches is a potential problem, you could go further and replace the mutex with a spinlock, but in most cases that's not strictly necessary)